# Symfony 4 - No session token after authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, token, symfony4

I've a problem with my authentication on my Symfony application.
After a authentification, I don't have the token for identified the user and I'm blocked on blank page without profiler.

So, look logs :

```
[2018-01-21 03:09:28] request.INFO: Matched route "security_login". {"route":"security_login","route_parameters":{"_locale":"fr","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login","_route":"security_login"},"request_uri":"http://snowtricks.jeremy-barette.fr/fr/login","method":"GET"} []

[2018-01-21 03:09:28] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []

[2018-01-21 03:09:29] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route":"_wdt","route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"818ef5","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://snowtricks.jeremy-barette.fr/_wdt/818ef5","method":"GET"} []

[2018-01-21 03:09:35] request.INFO: Matched route "security_login". {"route":"security_login","route_parameters":{"_locale":"fr","_controller":"App\\Controller\\SecurityController::login","_route":"security_login"},"request_uri":"http://snowtricks.jeremy-barette.fr/fr/login","method":"POST"} []

[2018-01-21 03:09:35] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.avatar AS avatar_2, t0.username AS username_3, t0.email AS email_4, t0.password AS password_5, t0.is_active AS is_active_6, t0.token_reset AS token_reset_7 FROM users t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["Arzaor"] []

[2018-01-21 03:09:36] security.INFO: User has been authenticated successfully. {"username":"Arzaor"} []
```

My configuration is very simple, I've a provider and firewalls, classic.

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        database_users:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/

            anonymous: true

            #http_basic: ~

            provider: database_users

            form_login:
                check_path: security_login
                login_path: security_login
                default_target_path: /
                always_use_default_target_path: true

            logout:
                path: security_logout
                target: /
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/(%app_locales%)/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

security_login :

```
public function login(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $utils): Response
{
    return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', [
        'lastUsername'  =>  $utils->getLastUsername(),
        'error'         =>  $utils->getLastAuthenticationError()
    ]);
}
```

You can test this bug on : http://snowtricks.jeremy-barette.fr/en/login with username : *Test* and password : *test*

Logs of my server:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Just to try, I initialized memory_limit to -1, but the page loads to infinity.

Thank you for you help

Comment: First: even if the page does not have a profiler, you could access it if you open a  profiler page and press the **Last 10** button or **Latest** button if the one you want to see was the last request or you could **search** for the profiler page with filters. Second: in the configurations you sent you did not include the access_control settings, you have still the **http_basic: ~** config, you are redirecting to a path *default_target_path: default* this option can have value of relative/absolute URL or a Symfony route name

Comment: Not informations for http_basic in the documentation... Default is the name of my route, so it’s normal and ok for the profiler, I test.

Comment: the http_basic config enables the basic HTTP authentication , but i assume you wish to use the form_login, so you do not need it.

Comment: please update your question with the access_control configurations

Comment: I've edited my question with the acces_control, new target and without http_basic.

Comment: I've add a account for test this bug, in the description of my problem.

Comment: Symfony does not create a profiler page for this issue. When you authenticate successfully it throws a HTTP 500 error, when the credentials are wrong, it works correctly. So you would have to search for logs in your server

Comment: provide us the `security_login` action to see if there is any issue with that

Comment: also try to use the configuration `always_use_default_target_path: true` after the `default_target_path`

Comment: I reset my server but without success... I edit my message

Comment: change the check_path with something else (e.g. security_check). That's the post url after clicking Login button so alos change your login html form action with check_path.

Comment: My problem is solved ! My serialize isn't correct, remove "$this" and it's good.

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Arzaor can you paste here the exact code for serialize ? I have a similar problem, but I can't understand how you solved it.

Comment: @GasKa No problem ! 

`public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->isLocked,
        ]);
    }`

Comment: Ok, I'm doing my best to make my app working, I know that is a problem with `serialize()`, but still can't find the proper variables for `serialize`. Thank you anyway! (If you have time, you can check my profile for my question)